# How find the file/test which is causing rake test task to terminate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake, rake-task, rake-test

I'm using a rake task to run the test suites of my application.
I can see that when I launch the task it run the command

```
ruby -I"lib:test" -I"[...]/lib" "[...]/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "vendor/plugins/shop/test/**/*_test.rb"
```

Where `[...]` is the path to the rake gem in my gemset.

When I run the task, I got some warnings and some `.` which means some tests pass but I end up with `terminated`

Log example :

```
...................................... 7431 Terminated
```

Notice that 7431 is the PID.

I cannot find any information about this case, verbose or trace option do not help me to figure out where my test suite is broken.

Is anybody knows what can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, what process creates the "Terminated"-message, but you could try the following:

Add a

```
def setup
  puts "Start test #{self.__name__}"
  STDOUT.flush
end
def teardown
  puts "Finished test #{self.__name__}"
  STDOUT.flush
end
```

to all of your tests.

Example:

```
require 'test/unit'

class Mytest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
    assert_equal(1,1)
  end
  def test_2
    assert_equal(1,1)
    exit 1  ##stops the execution
  end
  def test_3
    assert_equal(1,1)
  end
end
```

results in

```
Loaded suite test
Started
.>Exit code: 1
```

The test is stopped and you don't see where. I hope this is a similar situation to your "Terminate"-message.

Now add some code:

```
require 'test/unit'

class Mytest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    puts "Start test #{self.__name__}"
    STDOUT.flush
  end
  def teardown
    puts "Finished test #{self.__name__}"
    STDOUT.flush
  end
  def test_1
    assert_equal(1,1)
  end
  def test_2
    assert_equal(1,1)
    exit 1  ##stops the execution
  end
  def test_3
    assert_equal(1,1)
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
Loaded suite test
Started
Start test test_1
Finished test test_1
.Start test test_2
Finished test test_2
```

The last mentioned `test_2` is the one with the problem.

You may also add the `setup` and `teardown` to each TestCase (but if you have own definitions ot setup/teardown they will not contain the testcode).

```
require 'test/unit'

class Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    puts "Start test #{self.__name__}"
    STDOUT.flush
  end
  def teardown
    puts "Finished test #{self.__name__}"
    STDOUT.flush
  end
end
```

Don't forget to remove the code - it is only to identify where your problem may be.